# Html5 Video Player: Custom controls not displayed in full mode on Android-phone

Tags: javascript, html, video, controls, fullscreen

I made my player for the video on the site. I used Html5 technology.
Everything works well on the PC.
 But if i open my player on Android-phone in Full mode, controls not displayed.
[**IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2cC2.jpg)

Why this happen? I need help :)
**Open code my player THIS: [`CODE PEN`](https://codepen.io/magistr4815/pen/ZXWBEN)**

Answer (score 0):

The video and the custom controls should be in that container.Its not video you take to fullscreen but instead its container.I hope this help you.

Html code

```
<div id="videoContainer">
          <video>...<source></source>
          </video>
          <div> custom controls 
                <button>play/pause</button>
                <button id="fullscreenBtn" class="enterFullscreenBtn">fullscreen</button>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Js Code

```
var video=$('video');
$('#fullscreenBtn').on('click', function() {
 if (video.requestFullscreen)
 {
     $("#videoContainer").webkitRequestFullScreen();
 } 
});
```